# Flutter scroll down screen

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using Flutter to build a profile screen. I want to build a Profile screen like instagram profile screen, include multi widget like user background image, icon, user information and a Tab Bar show user old post or user image, but now I [can't scroll down this screen](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17HssSvyMjY4tngjqSU7Id8TEzfDw9MMM/view?usp=share_link)

I hope this screen can scroll down to view Tab Bar post or image, so after scroll down background image, user icon and other user information will hide

here is part of my code

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                200, // Adjust the height according to your needs,
            child: ListView(
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              children: <Widget>[
                ProfileWidget(),
              ],
            )));
  }

//include prodfile icon & profile backgroundimage 
  Widget ProfileWidget() {
    //control icon image location
    final _top = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 1 / 3 -
        MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 11.5;
    final HalfWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2;
    //username shower
    final bottom = profileHeight / 9;
    return Stack(
        clipBehavior: Clip.none,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        children: [
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: bottom),
            //background image control
            child: BGIImage(),
          ),
          Positioned(
            bottom: 0,
            right: 0,
            child: Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 20,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 5,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  border: Border.all(width: 0.8, color: Colors.white),
                  color: Colors.orange),
              child: IconButton(
                //add the function edit user icon
                onPressed: () {
                  _showSelectPhotoOptions(context);
                  //print(MediaQuery.of(context).size.height);
                  //print(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width);
                },
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.edit,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          //Icon UI control
          Positioned(top: _top, child: IconImage()),
          Positioned(top: _top * 1.6, child: Showusername()),
          Positioned(top: _top * 1.75, child: buildContent()),
          Positioned(top: _top * 1.9, child: dynamicBadge()),
          Positioned(
              top: _top * 2.15,
              right: HalfWidth * 1.25,
              child: FollowingLayer()),
          Positioned(
              top: _top * 2.15, right: HalfWidth * 0.4, child: FollowerLayer()),
          Positioned(top: _top * 2.4, child: PostOrGallery()),
        ]);
  }

//profile icon source & UI control
  Widget IconImage() => CircleAvatar(
        radius: profileHeight / 2.3,
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
          child: Image.network(
            _userIcon,
            errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) {
              return const Icon(Icons.error);
            },
            loadingBuilder: (context, child, loadingProgress) {
              if (loadingProgress == null) return child;
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                  value: loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes != null
                      ? loadingProgress.cumulativeBytesLoaded /
                          loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes!
                      : null,
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      );

//profile background image source & UI control
  Widget BGIImage() => Container(
        child: Image.network(
          _UserBGI,
          width: double.infinity,
          height: coverHeight,
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
          errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) {
            return const Icon(Icons.error);
          },
          loadingBuilder: (context, child, loadingProgress) {
            if (loadingProgress == null) return child;
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                value: loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes != null
                    ? loadingProgress.cumulativeBytesLoaded /
                        loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes!
                    : null,
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      );

  Widget Showusername() => Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
        child: Text(
          _username,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 17,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
        ),
      );

  Widget buildContent() => Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
        child: Text(
          _Selfintro,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 17,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
        ),
      );

  Widget dynamicBadge() => Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            Icon(Icons.coffee_outlined, color: Colors.black),
            SizedBox(
              width: 5,
            ),
            Icon(
              Icons.book_outlined,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 5,
            ),
            Icon(Icons.rocket_launch_outlined, color: Colors.black),
          ],
        ),
      );

  Widget FollowingLayer() => Container(
        // the Expanded widget lets the columns share the space
        child: Column(
          // align the text to the left instead of centered
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Following',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.black),
            ),
            Text(
              '10000',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.black),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );

  Widget FollowerLayer() => Container(
        // the Expanded widget lets the columns share the space
        child: Column(
          // align the text to the left instead of centered
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Follower',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.black),
            ),
            Text(
              '10000',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.black),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );

  Widget PostOrGallery() => Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
          20, // Adjust the height according to your needs,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      color: Colors.white,
      child: DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
        child: new Scaffold(
          body: new NestedScrollView(
            headerSliverBuilder:
                (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
              return <Widget>[
                new SliverAppBar(
                  backgroundColor: ui.Color.fromARGB(255, 209, 167, 107),
                  toolbarHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 100,
                  floating: true,
                  pinned: true,
                  snap: true,
                  bottom: new TabBar(
                    tabs: <Tab>[
                      new Tab(
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.content_copy_outlined,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                      ),
                      new Tab(
                          icon: Icon(
                        Icons.collections_outlined,
                      )),
                    ], // <-- total of 2 tabs
                  ),
                ),
              ];
            },
            body: new TabBarView(
              children: <Widget>[
                Center(child: CurrentUserPost()),
                Center(child: CurrentUserPost()),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ));
```

Thanks for watch and answer my question!

I had been try use *ListView*, but it doesn't help

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your `Scaffold` widget with `singlechildscrollView`

Comment: Hi, I'm using your suggestion wrap scaffold widget with singlechildscrollView , but now I get this error : FlutterError (BoxConstraints forces an infinite height.
These invalid constraints were provided to RenderStack's layout() function by the following function, which probably computed the invalid constraints in question:
  RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2430:11)
The offending constraints were:
  BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=390.0, h=Infinity))
I try to edit the height to fix this error but it doesn't work, do you have any suggestion how to solve it?